# Error when creating an EntityManager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I am trying to create an Entity manager to persist a object. Here is how I am doing that:

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.dv_model_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    Users user = new Users();
    user.setPassword("test2");
    user.setUserName("test2");

    tx.begin();
    em.persist(user);
    tx.commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

When I try to run this code in Netbeans, I can execute the first line and get a factory, however, after executing the esecond line, the program stops. There is no output. Any ideas why?

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.dv_model_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>com.dv.model.Users</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/esa"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the jdbc in the class path. It couldn't find the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting an error, such as your login failed.  Add a try catch and print the exception.  Or debug the code.